# NUnit and Selenium WebDriver

Tags: visual-studio-2013, selenium-webdriver, nunit

I was working on setting up Selenium in a project  today, and the thought came to mind: "Should I be using the NUnit framework in correlation with my Selenium tests?"

Here's my concern with using the NUnit framework: From the [NUnit website](http://www.nunit.org/), it states that: "NUnit is a unit-testing framework for all .Net languages". The purpose of the framework is to build unit tests, not integration tests.

Selenium tests are typically (I don't know of any instance when they aren't) integration tests. So, going back to my question, is it good practice to use a unit testing framework to do integration tests? Are there integration test frameworks that are robust enough to compete with NUnit, of which would be more appropriate?

Comment: NUnit is widely used with Selenium. You need to use some kind of framework in addition to Selenium(as people do TestNG/JUnit with Java) to make the test more streamlined. If you do not want to use NUnit then what other options do you have.?

Comment: @Saifur - it is possible to run unit/Selenium tests without NUnit in VS.

Comment: @MikeWeber I know it is. I did mention **to make the test more streamlined**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two main options for .NET development are, for the most part, NUnit, and MSTest.  IMHO, neither are very well optimized for automated browser tests.

You can force each to do what you want, but features such as TestNG's @DataProvider are a pain to implement, especially if you are dynamically changing your data provider for each test (say, loading your browsers to test through a properties file) -- this is trivial with TestNG, but NUnit and MSTest take a significant amount of "hacking" to make it work.

TL;DR version:  Someone really needs to port TestNG over to .NET  :)